# MOSS 2007 stripping out URL in SPListItem

Tags: splistitem, html, property

We have a SharePoint List with a multi-line text column.  In this column we have HTML code.  When I retrieve the column in an SPListItem, the url is often stripped from the string.

If the SharePoint site is at mysite.com then:

`<IMG alt="my alt tag." src="http://mysite.com/PublishingImages/logo.gif">`

becomes

`<IMG alt="my alt tag." src="/PublishingImages/logo.gif">`

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to stop this. This ensures that the URLs will be accessible regardless of the URL the user used to access the site. Since one site can have multiple addresses, any user will still see the same image regardless of site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for helping me with the previous version of this question. o____O